# Grails error - Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultQuartzConfig

Tags: java, grails, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin

Think I uninstalled or reinstalled the Grails cookie plugin and now I'm not sure what got changed in my Grails app, but I'm getting an error:

```
2011-12-29 10:22:05,356 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultQuartzConfig
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DefaultQuartzConfig
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:723)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:573)
    at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:519)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
    at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
```

I've tried a `grails clean` and tried uninstall / reinstalling quartz. How can I track down the source of the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, to fix it I copied the `ConfigQuartz` file to `DefaultConfigQuartz`. This seemed to resolve my issue. I hope it works for you!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it in a different way. 
I forced grails to download the your plugins again deleting all the plugin folders from:
.grails\1.3.7\projects\\plugins
In your case it should be enough to delete .grails\1.3.7\projects\\plugins\quartz-0.4.2